# Chrome Devtools - Make variable accessible across Multiple Windows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to make a variable accessible across multiple windows? I want to use Chrome Devtools console from different domains. Thank you~

[image]

Comment: just curious, why would you need to do this?

Comment: i'm just curious if it's possible

Comment: I dont think so. every new tab starts a new instance

Comment: oh okay thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with built-in dev tools, but you can achieve it with [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/), an extension which allows for cross-domain storage (among many other things). Set it up so that it exposes an interface on the `window` that sets and gets data:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             Shared Data
// @include          *
// @grant            GM_setValue
// @grant            GM_getValue
// ==/UserScript==

unsafeWindow.set = (prop, val) => GM_setValue(prop, val);
unsafeWindow.get = (prop) => GM_getValue(prop);
```

Then you can type in `set` and `get` into the console to easily set and get values across domains:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You would need some sort of server-side piece in play to have a "sharable" variable.

You could, however, use something like [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) to hook things up.

Example from the docs:

```
var db = new PouchDB('dbname');

db.put({
  _id: 'dave@gmail.com',
  name: 'David',
  age: 69
});

db.changes().on('change', function() {
  console.log('Ch-Ch-Changes');
});
```

Assuming you're on the same domain, it will work.